# Do you know any research regarding so-called "scroll arrow" used for vertical scrolling?

Tags: scrolling, research, guidelines, intuition

Currently, I started to be concerned about the "scroll arrow" within the interface. The scroll arrow indicates that the first visible section it's not all and it's more content to scroll. I was trying to find any research about it. Is it bad or good habit? In the example below the scroll, the arrow indicates that there are more options to pick from withing a form - ( just for an example ).
Personally I believe that's rather not a good solution. I'm curious about your point of view? Any insights/research?

[image: example of scroll arrow on mobile]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I think it's unnecessary, and counterproductive in case you have to put a back-to-top button if the form is too long.

There are other ways to indicate that there's more content.

One of the *Gestalt laws* says:

- **Closure**: The human eye prefers to see complete shapes. If the visual elements are not complete, the user can perceive a complete shape.

If the form container is shown as an incomplete shape, the user will scroll down to see it complete and indirectly will view all the content:

[image]

This is just one example, not a final design. I'm sure you can investigate other design options instead of resorting to the hackneyed arrow button.

Comment: As Don Norman once said: if you have to put a label on something your design has failed (or something along these lines)

Comment: I agree with you. I just was wondering if some research is available regarding it

Comment: Danielillo that's really goos solution! Thanks.

Comment: The "research" is application of the Gestalt Laws from psychology.